# Weblogic 12.1.3 error connecting domain with Eclipse (OEPE 12.2.1..2.1)

Tags: eclipse, dns, weblogic12c, eclipse-oxygen

Suddenly I am getting problem connecting Weblogic 12.1.3 with OEPE Mars, When I am trying to run server its giving:

> Error Connecting Weblogic Default Domain

However, I have de-installed Weblogic/JDK1.8/Eclipse and did fresh reinstall. Earlier it was working fine with the JDK1.8.

However, again I have de-installed Weblogic/JDK/Eclipse and reinstalled with updated version of Weblogic 12.2.1 with JDK1.8.162 (latest JDK8) and OEPE Oxygen to keep JDK version same in all the environments.

Now while I am trying to create server in Eclipse its giving me message:

> The Path C:\Oracle_JDeveloper12.2.1\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver doesn't contain a valid Weblogic Server Install or installed version is

I have installed JDeveloper 12.2.1.3 that comes with integrated Weblogic.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a weblogic domain by using config.cmd
Path: \Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\config.cmd

And update JAVA_HOME path in setDomainEnv.cmd at \Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\bin